# How do I make c-basic-offset stick in emacs?

Tags: emacs

In switching coding styles, I need to go from a one tab width of 4 indentation to a two space indentation.

I've added the following to my .emacs file, at the very end:

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq c-basic-offset 2)
```

Unfortunately, that's not working.  I still need to M-x set-variable for c-basic-offset, setting it to 2 for each file I open, to successfully change the indentation to 2 spaces instead of 1 tab.

Is there another config setting I need to add after these settings to make the new c-basic-offset stick?

Answer (score 4):

`c-basic-offset` is a per-buffer variable, so setting it in your `.emacs` won't work. You can use `(setq-default c-basic-offset 2)` or you can define a [mode hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/CC-Hooks.html) that executes every time you start `cc-mode`.

Comment: (setq-default c-basic-offset 2) at the end of my .emacs file doesn't have an effect.  Could another variable be overwriting the desired behaviour?

Comment: Perhaps. Are you also setting a style or a mode hook?

Answer (score 2):

```
M-x customize-variable c-basic-offset
```

From the docstring:

```
This variable automatically becomes buffer-local when set outside Custom.
However, setting it through Custom sets the default value.
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try `(setq-default tab-width 4)`

I have the following settings in my `.emacs` file, and it works for me:

```
(setq-default tab-width 2)
(setq js-indent-level 2)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
(setq css-indent-offset 2)
(setq sh-basic-offset 2)
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible alternate approach: use something like `(set-variable 'c-file-style "gnu")` to get the style you want. There is a pretty comprehensive list of built in styles, and you can define your own.